# sql server connection in android studio

Tags: android, sql

## android studio, how connect to sql server withpout a server ip sample http:\myhomepage:1433

i dont waht to connect use an ip sample:

```
111.111.1.111:1433
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect to your localhost server, you should be connected to the same network (Phone and the Computer with the server), just open cmd and type `ipconfig` and get the ip address for the server. in your android connection string enter `http://ipaddress/projectfolder`
You can only connect using the domain name `http://example.com` for a hosted live website since mobile devices won't recognize your localhost